# Как в конвертере один ко многим сделать обратное конвертирование (многие к одному)?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Здравствуйте. Есть конвертер

```
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var param = parameter as string;
        if (param!= null)
        {
            if (value is TwoPoints)
            {
                var points = (TwoPoints)value;
                if (IsActualFromToPoints(points))
                {
                    switch (param)
                    {
                        case "width":
                            return Math.Abs(points.Point1.X - points.Point2.X);
                        case "height":
                            return Math.Abs(points.Point1.Y - points.Point2.Y);
                        case "inverted":
                            return points.Orientation == Orientation.Horizontal ? points.Point1.Y < points.Point2.Y : points.Point1.X < points.Point2.X;
                        case "direction":
                            return points.Orientation == Orientation.Horizontal ? (points.Point1.X < points.Point2.X ? FlowDirection.LeftToRight : FlowDirection.RightToLeft) : (points.Point1.Y < points.Point2.Y ? FlowDirection.LeftToRight : FlowDirection.RightToLeft);
                        case "orientation":
                            return points.Orientation;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    switch (param)
                    {
                        case "width":
                            return double.NaN;
                        case "height":
                            return double.NaN;
                        case "inverted":
                            return false;
                        case "direction":
                            return FlowDirection.RightToLeft;
                        case "orientation":
                            return Orientation.Horizontal;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

То есть нужные мне свойства подтягивают значения из другого свойства (все из одного). Но хотелось бы описать и обратное конвертирование, вот только беда, для этого мне нужны сразу все значения или каким-то образом нужно получить действующий экземпляр свойства. Подскажите, как это можно осуществить? Может, есть какая-нибудь хитрость? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Обратное преобразование как в обычном, так и в мульти-конвертере предназначено для случаев, когда прямое преобразование обратимо. Если функция работает в одну сторону, то есть информация уничтожается, то из воздуха её взять не получится.

Стандартный способ использования конвертеров предполагает, что вы создаёте один экземпляр, кладёте его в ресурсы, а далее везде работаете с этим единственным экземпляром. То есть по сути это синглтон, две почти во всех отношениях статических функции.

Нюанс здесь в "почти". Если вы готовы создавать по отдельному экземпляру конвертера на каждый биндинг, то вы можете просто запоминать входящие аргументы при вызове `Convert`, а при вызове `ConvertBack` полагаться на них.

---

Например, вот надуманный пример конвертера, который берёт большее из двух значений (тем самым уничтожая при конвертации информацию о меньшем), но при обратной конвертации позволяет изменять большее значение.

```
public class MaxDoubleConverterExtension : MarkupExtension, IMultiValueConverter
{
    private double[] _values;

    public object Convert (object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        _values = values.Cast<double>().ToArray();
        return Math.Max(_values[0], _values[1]).ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack (object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        value = double.Parse((string)value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        return _values[0] > _values[1] ? new[] { value, Binding.DoNothing } : new[] { Binding.DoNothing, value };
    }

    public override object ProvideValue (IServiceProvider _) => new MaxDoubleConverterExtension();
}
```

Пример использования:

```
<Window x:Class="WeirdConverters.MainWindow" x:Name="root"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WeirdConverters"
        Width="300" Height="100">
    <TextBox>
        <TextBox.Text>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{local:MaxDoubleConverter}" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
                <Binding ElementName="root" Path="Width"/>
                <Binding ElementName="root" Path="Height"/>
            </MultiBinding>
        </TextBox.Text>
    </TextBox>
</Window>
```

Если менять размер окна, то в поле для редактирования будет отображаться большее из измерений: Width или Height. Если менять значение в поле, то будет изменяться это большее измерение, а прежнее останется неизменным.

Comment: А как их запоминать? То есть это не проблема, просто есть ряд вопросов. Экземпляр конвертера создается один раз при создании привязки (это важно)? Экземпляр одного и того же конвертера используется в одной привязке или для всех привязок с одним конвертером используется один экземпляр (ответ я скорее всего знаю, но все же)?

Comment: Я понимаю, что вопрос глупый. Просто я в конвертер добавил counter и получил странный результат 1 2 3 4 1 1 1

Comment: Дошло! Дело было не в бабине ))) просто я часть привязок сделал в коде, создав новые экземпляры конвертера )

Comment: Можно сделать конвертер одновременно markup extension, которое создаёт новый экземпляр конвертера при каждом вызове. Это упростит создание конвертера по каждому чиху в XAML.

Comment: Не, это, как раз, лишнее. Он не должен каждый раз создаваться )